# Find two non-constant functions that the composition is constant-

Tags: functions

Find two functions $f,g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ that are not constant such that their composition is constant?

Any help, please. Can these functions be found?

**EDIT:**
I try next, let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ define $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x\in\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$ and $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ define by $g(x)=|x|$. Then $g\circ f=1$. Is good my try?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Note that you aren't asking for continuous examples.  That should make it easy to construct examples.

Comment: @A.M. can you tell me if my attempt is ok?

Comment: @AndrewMadison yep absolutely, that is a valid and interesting example.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: what happens if you try to make $f,g$ as close to constant as possible i.e. $f(x_0)=C_0$ and $f(x)=C_1$ for all $x\neq x_0$?